# Background agent is scheduled but not launched by OS

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, background-agent

I have an issue with background agent execution in Windows Phone 8.
After a successful agent registration it wasn't executed by OS. 
I waited 5-10 days - no effect.
The issue is reproduced ONLY on two test devices (lumia 920 and htc x8).
All other devices shows normal agent execution log (about 5 other devices).

You can find the sample by the following link:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/19503836/2013-12-19%20TestApp_Release_AnyCPU_v1.2.xap

XAP:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/19503836/SimpleAgentApp.zip

- App registers clean agent and tracks agent launches
- App user interface displays that log

  1. no extra logic
  2. no time/memory consumable operations, it is almost clean project
  3. device battery level is over 50% all the time
  4. battery saver mode is disabled
  5. device has Cellular and Wifi access all the time
  6. device is used frequently
  7. it seems that other background agents are also not executed by OS

What could be wrong with background execution in system? 
How can I diagnose the issue?

I'm trying to find the issue for several months without any luck.

Comment: It's pure guess, but i think you are missing `ExtendedTasks` element.

Comment: this section is correct as background task works absolutely fine on other devices expect of those two specified above.

Comment: In Debug mode, are you using `ScheduledActionService.LaunchForTest` - does it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that those devices had some OS issues.
One test device was fixed by a hard reset and another one by a firmware update.